# Docker: trying to understand VOLUME in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-volume

First create a volume sample_vol

```
docker volume create sample_vol
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM archlinux/base

RUN touch /root/testing  [**edited** find note at RUN below]

# VOLUME sample_vol:/root  [**edited** this will not work, because VOLUME will not accpet named volumes. So this will not mount at /root, it will mount at sample_vol:/root which does not exist]

VOLUME "/root" or VOLUME ["/root"] [**edited** this will create a local mount volume only till the time the container is running. I tried to use named volumes like VOLUME ["name:/root"] but didnt work ]

# RUN touch /root/testing   [**edited** this will not work because volume when mounted will only copy files till it got declared]
```

build the image

```
docker build -t archlinux/sample_vol .
```

checking whether testing file is created in sample_vol

```
docker run --rm -it -v=sample_vol:/tmp/myvolume archlinux/base ls /tmp/myvolume
```

It does not show any file testing created

while

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name sample_vol archlinux/sample_vol ls /root/testing
```

It shows the file `testing` is created in the `/root/` of build image

So why `sample_vol` is not mounted at `/root` and `testing` is created inside it.

**Update: Reason i found can be due to**

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#volume

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps
>   change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those
>   changes will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding docker-volume.

Docker-Image are more about build time.
Docker-Volume is useful only in runtime.

Try running following commands to get an idea:

```
docker run --rm -it -v=sample_vol:/tmp/myvolume archlinux/base touch /tmp/myvolume/1.txt
docker run --rm -it -v=sample_vol:/tmp/myvolume archlinux/base touch /tmp/myvolume/2.txt
docker run --rm -it -v=sample_vol:/tmp/myvolume archlinux/base touch /tmp/myvolume/3.txt
docker run --rm -it -v=sample_vol:/tmp/myvolume archlinux/base ls -altr  /tmp/myvolume/
```

1st container create a file 1.txt in docker volume mounted at /tmp/myvolume and then container gets deleted after this operation.
2nd container create a file 2.txt in docker volume mounted at /tmp/myvolume and then container gets deleted after this operation.
3rd container create a file 3.txt in docker volume mounted at /tmp/myvolume and then container gets deleted after this operation.
4th container list files in docker volume mounted at /tmp/myvolume and then container gets deleted after this operation.

Docker volume is to store persistent data outside of the lifecycle of container.That means when you remove container , you still have data outside of the container living inside volume.

So next time if you create a container and attach that docker volume - you will automatically get all the data with new container.

Consider an example of database image where you want to have data in volume so that when you change the container to the higher version - you will get the old data in the new database.

Comment: So basically we have to use volumes only by `-v` in the  `docker run` command. Then why do we have `VOLUME` command in `Dokcerfile`

Comment: At `runtime` docker-engine will automatically creates a volume (if you do not attach manually) and attach it to the location that you have mentioned.

Comment: `At runtime docker-engine will automatically creates a volume`: `to the location that you have mentioned` : Do you mean `/root` here

Comment: can you see my updated question in the last. I think thats the reason